# How can I iterate starting at a particular key in a LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, traversal, linkedhashmap

If I have a data structure

```
Stock
{
  String Symbol;
  LinkedHashMap<Date,Double> DateForPrice;  
}
```

I know in the LinkedHashMap, I can get the stock price of specific date without traversing the whole list.

However, if I want to iterate through the LinkedHashMap of DateForPrice starting from a specific date, are there any way to do it without traversing the whole list?

Comment: Even if you can jump to a particular place, the iteration order of a `LinkedHashMap` will be the *insertion-order*, not the natural ordering of the keys; is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. The the stock price will be inserted in the order of date.

Answer (score 11):

`LinkedHashMap` doesn’t offer a way to start iterating in the middle of its ordered view of the map’s data. Supposing your use case is really that you want all dates after some `Date d` and to iterate those, then you should probably store your map as a [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). An important distinction here is that `LinkedHashMap`’s ordering is the *insertion-order*, and our supposed use-case here is that you want the natural *key-order*. `TreeMap`s maintain such a view, sorting the contents of the map by the map’s key.

`TreeMap`s have the additional benefit of allowing you to create slices of the map based on the key, so you can call [`tailMap(K k)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#tailMap(K)), to return the map with all keys occurring after `k`. In this case, you can call `tailMap` with your starting point, `d`.

e.g.:

```
TreeMap<Date, Double> dateForPrice;

// load up dateForPrice

Date start = // the point to start your iteration

for(Entry<Date, Double> entry : dateForPrice.tailMap(start).entrySet()){
    // loop code
}
```

`tailMap` method returns `SortedMap`, which is not iterable. But it has `entrySet` method returning `Set`, which is subinterface of `Iterable`.

Conveniently, if you want to keep storing your data in a `LinkedHashMap` you can simply load up a `TreeMap` with your current instance (with some performance tradeoff, of course):

```
TreeMap<Date, Double> dateSortedDateForPrice = new TreeMap<Date, Double>(dateForPrice);
```

Comment: in addition to tailMap() you can use subMap(Object fromKey, Object toKey), if you want to bound the new map you are creating. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Comment: +1: Worth mentioning that what you really want is any NavigableMap e.g. TreeMap.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use `TreeMap` instead - it will be sorted by date and you can use `tailMap` to get the required portion